# Toggle Switch not toggling after including ng-model and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, toggle

Hi I have created a plunker added the link in comment,the problem is that the toggle switch is not behaving as expected, but the same behavior is working as expected when I use normal checkBox. So can any one help in figuring out the problem with the toggle switch. why it is not behaving as expected.

In toggle switch even though I change any other apart from 1st switch its toggling only the 1st switch no matter which switch you are toggling.

But this problem is not there with checkbox.

Comment: link to plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/urHOsN?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are referring to the same id every time in the `<label for="">` place. I've added the index of the ng-repeat to make it refer to the specific item in the ng-repeat.

Here is the updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EfkFP44RL3y5Jo2xeOVW?p=preview

This is what I have changed:

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="userCredentials.active" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="paybycampusCardonoffswitch{{$index}}" />
              <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="paybycampusCardonoffswitch{{$index}}">
```